# How can I remove or modify the header and footer of generated PDFs?

Tags: orbeon

The "no template" PDFs generated via the PDF button include a header and a footer. How can I remove or modify the header and footer for all generated PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding in your own CSS the existing CSS rules in the `@page` section of [`form-runner-base.less`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/style/form-runner-base.less).